# GA4: How to access datalayer variables in an array

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

The GA4 documentation contains examples of data layer variables like:

```
gtag("event", "add_payment_info", {
  currency: "USD"
  items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee"
    }
  ]
});
```

I know how to access the currency value for reporting, but I have not managed to access items in the "items" array.

I tried it with a Java script custom variable but without success:

```
function() {
  //alert("In function");

  if (eventObject.event === "add_payment_info" ) {
      //alert("In condition");
      var desiredValue = eventObject.items[1].value;  // should get "Stan and Friends Tee"
  
  }
  return desiredValue;
}
```

It never makes it into the condition, never mind returning the actual value.